# How to listen iTunes podcasts on Android

Tags: podcast, itunes

I found a language learning website. They offer their podcasts for free but only an iTunes link is provided. So iTunes for me, downloaded them all and put in a nice playlist to go through one by one and listen and learn.

I don't own an iPhone but I own an Android phone, a Google Nexus S.

How can I get all these podcasts in a playlist on my phone?

I am on Mac-os-x Lion, I think.

Comment: Can't add a new answer. For something more current, try the [AntennaPod app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.danoeh.antennapod).

Comment: I've found that Castbox is able to play any podcast that i've ever needed.

Comment: @Walf I've unprotected the question, feel free to post an answer with detailed info.

Comment: @AKDiscer I've unprotected the question, feel free to post an answer with detailed info.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't want to be shackled to iTunes for downloading/syncing the actual episodes, you can right-click the podcast in iTunes, and select *Copy Podcast URL*. It will copy the URL to the podcast feed to your clipboard.

[image: Screenshot]

Use this URL on your Android device to subscribe to the podcast there.

Answer (score 3):

I've faced the same problem and I found this software:

http://doubletwist.com/

Basically what it does is read you iTunes library and coping what you want to the device your want, it's just great and you can set the configs to you needs.

It has an android client and a PC client.

Hope you will find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

Manual alternative

If you are on a computer and you don't even have iTunes installed, you can find web page of that podcast on iTunes site

example: http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/tiesto-s-club-life-podcast/id251507798

Then you can view source of the page and locate links to actual files - mp3 or m4a . You can download the files saving either directly to a connected phone or transfer later in bulks.

Comment: Viewing source might be overwhelming for most users, why not use Feedflipper or Tunesviewer to get copyable url?

Answer (score 0):

You could always just get an iPhone ;-P

seriously though, I would contact the provider of the podcast. Many times they can make available the RSS feed, which many apps on Google Play can translate into a usable podcast. If they do not provide access this way, then unfortunately you are stuck unless someone engineers a way to access iTunes podcasts.

Comment: All podcasts on iTunes Directory have an RSS, that was submitted to iTunes' podcast directory - This means you can subscribe using Tunesviewer and Swallowcatcher on Android, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [iSyncr](http://www.jrtstudio.com/iSyncr-iTunes-for-Android). It will download your podcasts over USB/WiFi/Mac/PC. I've also added some specific podcast features like bookmark syncing, which work in combination with my other app, [Rocket Player](http://www.jrtstudio.com/Rocket-Player-Android-Media-Player), so that you can listen to half a podcast on your computer and the other half while you are on the road.

Just a note from the developer.